# Covariance matrix of least square estimator with measurements having different variances

Tags: statistics, estimation, least-squares

If I have a linear least square fit, where the $y$ values all have different variances, than the estimator for the parameter is written as follow:
$$
\vec{\theta} = (A^T V^{-1}A)^{-1}A^TV^{-1}\vec{y}
$$

Apparently (because a question on a worksheet is asking it), using standard error propagation, one can show, that the variance is
$$
V(\vec{\theta}) = (A^TV^{-1}A)^{-1}
$$
I cant work this out myself, and so far, all the proofs I have seen for the Variance of the linear least square fits were, when the $y_i$ all having the same Variance, but I need this more general form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $var(Y) = V$ and denote $B = (A'V^{-1}A)^{-1}A'V^{-1}$, hence 
\begin{align}
var(\hat{\theta}) &=  var(By)\\
 &= Bvar(y) B^T\\
 & = BVB^T\\
 &= (A'V^{-1}A)^{-1}A'V^{-1} V V^{-1}A(A'V^{-1}A)^{-1}\\
 &= (A'V^{-1}A)^{-1}(A'V^{-1}A)(A'V^{-1}A)^{-1}\\
 &= (A'V^{-1}A)^{-1}.
\end{align}